# Why don't stock DSLR camera straps have quick-releases on them? And where can I find a simple strap that does?

Tags: camera-straps, quick-release

I have a D7000 and recently got a BlackRapid RS7 strap for it. I love the RS7, but there are times when I'd rather have just a simple strap attached to the eyelets on the camera.

The standard Nikon strap that comes with the D7000 (same on my D80 & D50) can only be attached/removed by threading the nylon in insanely intricate ways.

What I want is a small, secure clip that will clip to the eyelets on the camera body.

I have not been able to find anything like that. Nor have I been able to find a simple strap that has a built-in clip mechanism.

(Related question: What do people do with the existing eyelets when they use something like an RS7 all the time?  They are not removable and are pretty annoyingly in the way.

Answer (score 15):

Anything quick release represents a point of inherent weakness - a breaking point.

Any QR system has a means of releasing it, be it a movement in a specific direction or clasping of 2 points on the clip itself. These can be activated by mistake when they come into contact with other clothing or your bag.

I have known quite a few people have theirs go unexpectedly on them and end up with a smashed camera. The intricate attachment of the strap makes it more secure.

I use Black Rapid straps which do have quick release buckles on them but they are very secure and usually away from anything else which could clash with them. I haven't found the eyelets to be an issue or annoying but I have Canon gear so I can't comment on your Nikon.

Comment: I agree completely. Is the slight time saved by a quick release worth the increased risk of a smashed camera? I only just trust the normal straps on my camera as it is!

Comment: With a good release mechanism there is no danger of accidentally triggering it.  You trust QR plates on a tripod right?

Comment: The RS7 comes with a solid pieces that screws into the tripod mount, I don't worry about that part failing. For the plastic buckle in back I wrapped a Velcro security cable tie between the two pieces so even if it disintegrated it would not instantly drop my camera.

Comment: Yes, it is the plastic buckle I was referring to - I find it very sturdy - was just mentioning it's construction

Comment: @Kendall Helmstetter Gelner no, I do not trust the QR plate on my tripod, I always double check it is properly secured and always pick the camera and tripod up by the camera so that only the tripod falls if it has become partly undone.

Comment: QR plates aren't vertical, and no, I don't fully trust them (having them mounted wrong and coming loose while shooting a few times, I now keep the strap around my neck even when using the camera on tripod).

Comment: Another factor is that any QR strap would be very quick for a thief or mugger to release as well, possibly without you noticing...

Comment: Never had a QR strap accidentally open after 3 years of almost daily use. Turns out it is a very comfortable strap, I almost never use the QR and wish it didn't have one because the superfluous threading. Here's the one: http://www.ephotozine.com/article/lexar-professional-camera-strap--review-7469

Comment: @jwenting The QR plate should be mounted correctly. User error.

Answer (score 11):

Simple, because they do not need to. As Micheal Reichmann says, *The Enemy of Excellent is Good Enough*.

Would you buy a different camera if the other one had quick-releases on its strap? Probably, no. So why would the manufacturer pay more to make the strap? Long ago, my cameras came with an awesome strap with a fastener for the lens cap and holder for battery but they stopped doing that. Eventually, they figured out they can save money doing stuff that does not bring them more money!

Comment: That's Voltaire, not Michael Reichmann. :) Anyway, I'm voting you up, because I think you're spot on, but I also think it's interesting that the common use of this aphorism is the _opposite_ — striving for perfection often prevents people from implementing something that would be perfectly good enough, and so we end up with nothing at all.

Comment: To quote Mark Zuckerberg: Done is better than perfect.

Answer (score 6):

I use OpTech with pro-loop. Aside from the QR, this strap also has strecthing neoprene/membrane, where it helps ease the burden of shouldering your camera/lens combo. I actually have 2 straps for 4 cameras, since mostly I only use/bring 2 cameras at any given moment/trip. For the rest, I just attach the loop on the camera and exchange/swap the neoprene strap as needed.

Where to get: http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/118283-REG/OP_TECH_USA_1501372_Pro_Loop_Strap_Black.html

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the Pacsafe strap:
http://pacsafe.com/www/index.php?_room=3&_action=detail&id=170

It has a spring-loaded self-locking mechanism that is simple to unhook yet should not come off accidentally. It has some spongy sleeves that can slide over the mechanism to make it inaccessible as well. Like other Pacsafe products, it features a built-in metal wire so that the strap cannot be slashed.

Comment: This looks really good. However, I wish Nikon used the strap attachments like shown in the pictures here: http://www.amazon.com/PacSafe-Carry-Anti-Theft-Camera-Strap/dp/B004LL5MZW/ref=sr_1_2?tag=kindsyst-20 . That way there'd be less hardware involved; the Nikon rings are annoying.

Answer (score 4):

I have been using Lowepro Transporter Camera Strap: [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B000H7GFWS/ref=wms_ohs_product_T2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000H7GFWS) for about 3 years now..

Apart from the quick release clips, the strap itself is great and helped reduce neck pain when walking around with a long lens attached.

Comment: +1 I also use the Transporter. The built-in memory card pocket (holding a spare) has saved me several times when I have jumped out with camera only, card still in computer.

Answer (score 4):

I use a Domke 1" camera strap with my Pentax K-7. I usually use small prime lenses (the reason to shoot with Pentax, after all!), and I don't need a camera strap with more bulk than my camera + lens — something that frustrated me with most of the fancy camera straps. This one is comfortable yet simple, and doesn't have obnoxious bright-colored advertising written on it.

I don't use the QR version, but one exists: [Domke Gripper Camera Strap 1" with Swivel Quick Release - Black, from B&H](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/16182-REG/Domke_741_6BK_1_Web_Camera_Strap.html), and that model has a design where the strap should never get twisted the wrong way, which seems handy. Tiffen (who make the Domke brand) offer a selection of colors (all neutral and boring — black, tan, or navy) and you can choose between 1" or 1.5" if you have more hefty equipment.

Answer (score 1):

The Leica strap has a very clever and safe mechanism.
It's not as quick to release as those plastic squeeze buckles, but certainly faster than threading webbing through buckles or the typical split ring. There's also no way it will release by accident. There are some photos at Amazon:

[http://www.amazon.com/Leica-Carry-Strap-Cameras-14312/dp/B0000BZM1F/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1345164599&sr=8-1&keywords=leica+strap](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000BZM1F)

Answer (score 1):

UPstrap® uses releases designed for the military.  The smaller release for 3/4" web is 120 lbs. breaking strength and the large one is 300 lbs. breaking strength.  The larger quick release has a definitive audible click when it mates.  [UPstrap camera straps](http://www.upstrap-pro.com).

In addition the non-slip shoulder pad remains on your shoulder.  It does not slip off.