# Is there an easy way to change between camera straps?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, camera-straps

I've got a Nikon with the default camera strap and I bought a BlackRapid shoulder strap. I had in mind being able to use either of them, but not both at the same time. The problem is that I find it takes some time to change between straps, usually when I remove or reattach the neck strap.

Is there any alternative that would let me detach and reattach the neck strap without having to remove it entirely? More or less like BlackRapid's hook that you can attach or detach from the bottom of the camera.

In case they're different depending on the camera, I have a Nikon D90.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why don't stock DSLR camera straps have quick-releases on them? And where can I find a simple strap that does?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12413/why-dont-stock-dslr-camera-straps-have-quick-releases-on-them-and-where-can-i)

Comment: @MichaelClark - I don't see the duplication there. This question implies he wants quick release for his existing two straps, the other asks about alternative straps that could be found.

Comment: The reason for wanting to disconnect the neck strap may be different, but the problem and solution is the same: How to turn a neck strap that threads through the connectors on the camera into a quick attach/detach strap.

Comment: Out of curiosity: in what situation would you prefer the neck strap over the shoulder strap?

Comment: @BartArondson: I usually change to neck strap when using a tripod or having someone else taking the photo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have mentioned, I recommend using a quick release system for your standard strap. The one I use is a [Tamrac N-15](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000AB4NW) and, when disconnected, it leaves behind a minimal amount of strapping that stays mostly out of the way.

For your BlackRapid (or any sling strap for that matter), I use a tiny, 1-inch, Arca Swiss clamp made by [Kirk Enterprises](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006U43AMA). This way, I leave my Arca Swiss plate always attached to my camera and the Kirk clamp is always attached to my sling strap.

It then should take you all of a 2-3 seconds to remove the sling clamp and instantly go to your regular strap or even a tripod which I tend to use a lot.

The use of this Arca Swiss plate and clamp system is also very flexible in that when changing lenses, to say a 70-200 f/2.8 that has its own tripod foot, you simply move the sling strap clamp to it for proper carrying. This is a scenario where the standard strap would not work.

Comment: I ended buying the [Lowepro Transporter Camera Strap](http://www.amazon.com/Lowepro-34958-Transporter-Camera-Strap/dp/B000H7GFWS), as a quick-release strap works fine and I can switch easily between them.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach [these](http://optechusa.com/system-connectors/mini-qd-loops.html) to your camera's attachment points, then loop the ends of your strap through the detachable ends. I've not used them, but they are supposed to be rated for 44lbs static weight.

You could also make this [DIY](http://fstoppers.com/how-to-make-your-own-quick-release-camera-strap) hook to attach your regular neck strap to the Black Rapid connector. If you want to use a Manfrotto RC2 plate with the Black Rapid strap, you need to replace the stock Manfrotto screw with the [FR-T1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0049H89F8) fastener from Black Rapid. It is stronger than the flip out ring that was not designed to support the weight of anything.

Comment: Yikes, I don't know that I'd trust that first one to hold my camera, especially with a decent lens on it!

Comment: I agree with Joanne, the first one looks kinda weak to hold a medium weight camera.

Comment: The thin cable that threads through the lug on your camera is rated for 45lbs.

Comment: WARNING: I have tried using the Manfroto quick release plate for the purpose mentioned here and killed my DSLR and attached lens when the flip-out ring on the Manfroto screw finally snapped off. It seems like it's strong enough, but I can attest with first hand experience, IT'S NOT!! In fact, because of this I now don't even trust the BlackRapid FastenR FR-T1 and only use the FastenR FR-3 which is a solid, continuous, piece of metal.

Comment: If you want to use the Manfrotto RC2 plate with the Black Rapid strap, you need to replace the stock screw with the FR-T1 fastener from Black Rapid. It is stronger than the flip out ring that was not designed to support the weight of anything.  http://www.amazon.com/BlackRapid-RFH-1E0-Fastenr-Tripod-FR-T1/dp/B0049H89F8/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1365715448&sr=1-1&keywords=FRT-1

Comment: JoanneC: With any large lens the strap needs to be attached to the tripod collar on the lens, not the camera body.

Comment: @MichaelClark - I wasn't thinking a lens that needed a tripod collar... It just looked a little weak to me.

Answer (score 0):

Just search "camera neck strap with quick release" on Amazon and you will find products from all the major accessory/straps/bags manufacturers, most of them aren't terribly expensive.

I haven't used any of them myself.